# Compute Sunlight or Shade

Tags: windows, software-rec, google-maps, google-earth

I have a 3D building (Google SketchUp, displayed in Google Earth (or Maps)).

Google earth has a feature to "show sunlight across a landscape".  How do I show the building's shadow throughout the day?  If easier, how can I view the sunlight going into the hitting the sides of the building throughout the day (the angle is most important to me).

Is there a plugin or an add on or entirely different software that could do this for me?

Answer (score -1):

take a look at [this](http://support.google.com/sketchup/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114938).

I think that this support page answers your question in particular look at the time slider for  the angle throughout the day